# Get the value of array1 specifing the value of the array inside the values of array1

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I think that from the title it's not entirely clear, but this is the situation:

I have an array like this one (it's bigger, this is just an example):

```
$array = array(
    array('name' => 'John', 'age' => '29', 'from' => 'Uknown'),
    array('name' => 'Brad', 'age' => '27', 'from' => 'Idk'),
    array('name' => 'Phil', 'age' => '31', 'from' => 'My House')
);
```

I'm trying to find a fast-way using native functions of PHP (without using loops or other things) that specifing the name of this array inside another array, it gives me back the info related to this name.

Example:

If I specific `Brad` it gives me back an array with:

```
array('name' => 'Brad', 'age' => '27', 'from' => 'Idk')
```

Comment: i don't think you can do that without checking the name field. even if there's a native function for this, it'll be using loops under the hood

Comment: You're right, I wasn't very clear in the message. I meant without using loops and do a new function when there's an approach cleanier and easier using native functions of PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my approach

```
$key = array_search('Brad', array_column($array, 'name'));

print_r($array[$key]);
```

**For reference** 
[PHP docs : array-search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) 
[PHP docs : array-column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your don't have duplicate item and duplicate name.

```
$names = array_column($array, 'name');
$indexs = array_flip($names);
print_r($array[$indexs['Brad']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such functions. The only option you have is to rebuild your array as:

```
$array = array(
    'John' => array('name' => 'John', 'age' => '29', 'from' => 'Uknown'),
    'Brad' => array('name' => 'Brad', 'age' => '27', 'from' => 'Idk'),
    'Phil' => array('name' => 'Phil', 'age' => '31', 'from' => 'My House')
);
```

And use simple `isset`:

```
if (isset($array['Brad'])) {
    print_r($array['Brad']);
} else {
    echo 'Brad not found';
}
```

And of course if `name` values repeat in your array, you have to create more unique keys.

Comment: yes there is.... and you don't have to rebuild anything

Comment: @VikingCode hiding loops under the hood, okay.